# Auto format azure bicep file

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

How to auto format azure bicep files to have common way for writing/format code
from

```
param instLocation array = [
    'euw'
]
```

to

```
param instLocation array = ['euw']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To auto format azure bicep file, you can use

- format via the VS Code UI. View -> Command palette... then type format document
- use cli `az bicep format` that will come out with next release, https://github.com/Azure/bicep/pull/8580

Answer (score 0):

You can set auto-formatting in VS Code with settings. It's best practice to configure this per project.

Putting this in your `.vscode/settings.json` will do the job:

```json
{
  "editor.formatOnSave": true,
  "[bicep]": {
    "editor.defaultFormatter": "ms-azuretools.vscode-bicep",
  }
}
```